# something went wrong. We’ll take you back to checkout so you can try again erron error paypal express checkout?

Tags: woocommerce, paypal

We are currently facing an issue with Woocommerce paypal express checkout plugin,

When we are trying to do the payment with paypal credit or debit card option it showing the following error “something went wrong. We’ll take you back to checkout so you can try again.”

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-gateway-paypal-express-checkout/issues/596
They say Paypal fixed the issue on both production and sandbox accounts. But we are still facing the issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

That is the only error the Debit/Credit card button ever displays.

It can occur in normal and expected situations, such as declines.

Declines can happen when doing tests on your own account.

If you need particular declines to be researched, you'll need to contact PayPal.

The error message does not imply a technical problem, and it is not something that can be solved by Stack Overflow.

If the error message occurs for *every single* customer's payment attempt, with zero successes, it can sometimes be due to an account factor like your *business type* not being suited for this type of card processing. For that the account owner will need to contact PayPal's business support via https://www.paypal.com/smarthelp/contact-us